# RemoteControlReceivedWithEvent in iOS 7 issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, ios7

I am having a hard time trying to figure out why in iOS 7 the remote controls don't work. In iOS 7, in the lock screen or even in the Control Center, the buttons are unresponsive and the funny thing is that it works fine on iOS 6.

Here is the code I use:

```
- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)receivedEvent {

if (receivedEvent.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl) {

    switch (receivedEvent.subtype) {

        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
             if (player.playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying) {

                 [player pause];
             }
             else {
                 [player play];
             }
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPreviousTrack:
            break;

        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack:
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}}
```

This is where I found the information about how to perform this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Remote-ControlEvents/Remote-ControlEvents.html

Any ideas why this is happening? It works on iOS 6 but not iOS 7.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into this same problem and I ended up removing the case statement **UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause** and added case statements **UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay** and **UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause** individually. I don't have an good explanation for why this changed.

*UPDATE*

I found that **UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause** is called when the user is using their headset to control the player. Just a FYI.

Comment: Perfect! Worked just like I wanted to! Thanks

Comment: Well played, you just save my time

Answer (score 0):

I think its a better solution:

```
case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay:
case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause:
   if (_paused) {
      [self play:self];
   } else {
      [self pause:self];
   }
   break;
```